# NSOutlineView with source list highlighting not indenting second level

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I ran into a very strange problem:

I have an `NSOutlineView` set to `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList`. Under certain conditions, the second level is not indented and shown at the same level as the root node.

I believe that is, because the first level is expected to be a "group" level. However, on 10.8 everything is indented properly by default. I only caught this while testing on 10.7. Looks like this behavior changed across releases.

Second level is not indented if:

- on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion (always same behavior)
- OR on 10.8 **only** if I implement  `- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item` to return NO

How can I get each level to be indented as one would expect for a hierarchal layout and keep the source list style?

*Unexpected indentation:*

[image: unexpected indentation]

Comment: Try changing the the outline view from Source to Regular or Normal. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979212/nsoutlineview-indentation-issue

Comment: @MichaMazaheri `[...] and keep the source list style?`..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the indentation only starts on the 3rd level. So, to get around this, you need to add a node that wraps all your current root nodes. That root node will be styled much like the default OSX group node:

[image]

Not ideal, depending on your UI, but better than using the regular NSOutlineView styling.

If you don't want to show the root header, you could use `outlineView:heightOfRowByItem:` to set the height to `0`.